# How to remove an item from ListView using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, listview

I have the following `ListView`:

[image]

and I'm creating a `List<string>`  of the items I want a list of rows to remove from that ListView:

```
List<String> lst =new List<String>{"A1","A2"};
```

I know that I can delete the rows using iterating through the index and deleting the item using `RemoveAt()` function, but is there any way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `A1`/`A2` are the keys, no LINQ is required:

```
foeach(var a in new[] { "A1", "A2" })
    lw.Items.RemoveByKey(a);
```

Why not?

---

But if you want to use LINQ at any cost, write you own extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
        action(item);
}
```

and use it this way:

```
new[] { "A1", "A2" }.ForEach(a => lw.RemoveByKey(a));
```

However keep in mind that this is a well-known but disputable approach.

btw, `List<T>` already has such extension method, but my works for any `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
new List<string> { "A1", "A2" }.ForEach(); // evokes List<T>.ForEach
new[] { "A1", "A2" }.ForEach(); // evokes my
new List<string> { "A1", "A2" }.AsEnumerable().ForEach(); // evokes my, I guess
```

Comment: If the `List<String>` contains more than two we can not do this right? But Iterating through the `List` we can do this. But i just need a LINQ approch( this is just for learning purpose only )

Comment: If you have a list like that you can iterate through the list and use the above mentioned solution. You should also be able to use lw.Items.RemoveByKey( string key).

Comment: The extension approach looks cool and "LINQ"y but seems to be overly complicated. I understand that this is just a learning example but the ListViewItemCollection is not really good for these things as it needs to be extended for the LINQ-things to work. There will be iteration somewhere, either tucked away in the extension method or more straight forward as in the former solution by abatishchev.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can make a list of excluded items (and populate them however you want, but in this case I'm choosing a compile time list.  Then you simply select all items in the first list and use the `Except` method to exclude items from the other list.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>{"A1", "A2", "A3" };
List<string> excludedList = new List<string>{ "A1", "A2" };

var list = lst.Select(e => e)
              .Except(excludedList);

foreach (var a in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + "\n"); //Displays A3
}
```